# Solving differential equation by exact method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

I am trying to solve this equation by method of reducing to exact equation ; i.e. $M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0$

The equation is $dy/dx = \cos^2y / \sin^2x$

$∂M/∂y = 2\cos y \sin y$

$∂N/∂x = 2\cos x \sin x$

Clearly it is not exact. I tried making it exact using $μ(x)$, $μ(y)$ and $μ(xy)$ but to no avail.

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote :
$$M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0$$

$$dy/dx = \cos^2y / \sin^2x$$

$$∂M/∂y = 2\cos y \sin y$$

$$∂N/∂x = 2\cos x \sin x$$

This is false because you made a mistake in the  calculus of $N$ and $M$

$$dy/dx = \cos^2y / \sin^2x\quad\implies\quad -\frac{dx}{\sin^2(x)}+\frac{dy}{\cos^2(y)}=0 $$
Now this is the correct form $\quad M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0\quad$ thus :
$$M(x,y)=-\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}$$
$$N(x,y)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(y)}$$
As a consequence 
$$∂M/∂y =∂N/∂x = 0$$

This is the simplest case of $∂M/∂y =∂N/∂x$ .

Thus $\quad-\frac{dx}{\sin^2(x)}+\frac{dy}{\cos^2(y)}=0\quad$ is exact.

The integrating factor is $\mu=1$ as is is wellknown for all exact DE.

So, one can directly integrate it for :
$$\cot(x)+\tan(y)=c$$
$$y(x)=\tan^{-1}\left(c-\cot(x) \right)$$

Comment: @Axion004. You'r right. A beautiful series of typos. Now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

$$dy/dx = \cos^2(y) / \sin^2(x)$$
$$\frac  {dy} {\cos^2(y)}-\frac {dx} {\sin^2(x)} =0$$
Rewrite it as:
$$  d(\tan (y)) +d(\text {ctg} (x)) =0$$
It's exact.
$$  Nd(\tan (y)) +Md(\text {ctg} (x)) =0$$
$$M(\tan (y),\text {ctg} (x))=N(\tan (y),\text {ctg} (x))=1$$

Comment: Why isn't Integrating factor not calculatable using what I did? Just using dx and dy?

Comment: It's already exact no need for integrating factor @user68153 Note that your differential equation is easy to solve with other methods. It's separable :$$\frac {dy} {\cos^2 y}=\frac {dx} {\sin^2 x}$$

Comment: @ user68153. The ntegrating factor is calculable using what you did but if you don't make a mistake in the calculus of $N$ and $M$ : See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $$dy/dx = \cos^2y / \sin^2x$$ is exact if you write it as $$\csc ^2 x dx-\sec ^2 y dy =0$$